# Automated dump file generation, is there a registry setting?

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

Today for generating dump files I'm using the SysInternals tool ProcDump, with such a command running in a cmd window:

```
:loop

net stop "MyService"
net start "MyService"

echo Monitoring Access violations
procdump.exe -e -g -ma MyApplication.exe MyDumpFile.dmp > log.txt

goto loop
```

But is there another way to tell directly Windows to create dump whenever one application crashes ?

For example I found this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl`
that enables dump to be generated by Windows, but only when the system crashes.

Is there an equivalent key or Windows setting for generating Dump when one Application, or Service crashes ?

It is to be used by a QA service, and I would like it to be the less intrusive possible. Running procdump look to them like an added tool, a plugged in tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed, from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to create this key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
```

then populate the required settings:

- `DumpFolder` - the equivalent of the minidump folder for user folders i.e. where dumps are stored. Since this is per-user that user will need write access to the location.
- `DumpType` - whether to perform a full memory dump, or just a minidump.

In this folder, the settings apply to *any* application that crashes. If you want to match a specific process, create a subfolder with the process name e.g. `myapphasabug.exe` and apply the custom settings there, which override the default.

Perhaps this is more than you need, but the [codeproject minidumper example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu) is a very helpful starting point for adding "self-dumping"/support code to an application, should you wish your app to automate the "there is a dump, please sent this to support" process.

Also, consider turning on the [application verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for stricter testing - like the driver verifier it can catch issues before you ship them and is very handy.